# Blur event happens before datepicker fills the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, onblur

I made a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. Reading some questions/answers here on SO, I added

```
onSelect: function() {        
                    date_input.blur();
            },
```

to the datepicker, although this is still not working for me. Any idea why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
<link id="bsdp-css" href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--  jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
   <!--
      function validate() {
      
         if( document.invia_dati.nome.value == "" ) {
            alert( "Please provide your name!" );
            document.invia_dati.nome.focus() ;
            return false;
         }
      }

   function validate_field(field_id, error_id) {
    var field = document.getElementById(field_id);
    var perror = document.getElementById(error_id);
    if (field.value === "") {
      perror.style.display = "block";
      field.style.borderColor = "red"
      field.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px red";
    } else {
      perror.style.display = "none";
      field.style.borderColor = "LightGrey"
      field.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px LightGrey";
    }
  }
   //-->

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="data_nascita"]'); //our date input has the name "data_nascita"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: "top",
            onSelect: function() {        
              date_input.blur();
      },
        })
    })
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" name="invia_dati" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<fieldset>


<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Invia Dati:</legend>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="data_nascita">Data di Nascita</label>
<div class="col-md-4 date">
    <input class="form-control" id="date" name="data_nascita" placeholder="13/11/1995" type="text" onblur="return(validate_field('date', 'dob-errore'));">
    <p id="dob-errore"> Questo campo non può essere vuotο</p>  
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="pob">Luogo di nascita</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="pob" name="pob" type="text" placeholder="i.e. Roma" class="form-control input-md" onblur="return(validate_field('pob', 'pob-errore'));">
  <p id="pob-errore"> Questo campo non può essere vuotο</p>    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button (Double) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="binvio"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="binvio" name="binvio" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Invio</button>
    <button id="bannulla" name="bannulla" type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse">Annulla</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written in the documentation of datepicker events: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate

You need to listen to the `changeDate` event!

```js
    <!--
    function validate() {

      if (document.invia_dati.nome.value == "") {
        alert("Please provide your name!");
        document.invia_dati.nome.focus();
        return false;
      }
    }

    function validate_field(field_id, error_id) {
      var field = document.getElementById(field_id);
      var perror = document.getElementById(error_id);
      if (field.value === "") {
        perror.style.display = "block";
        field.style.borderColor = "red"
        field.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px red";
      } else {
        perror.style.display = "none";
        field.style.borderColor = "LightGrey"
        field.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px LightGrey";
      }
    }
    //-->

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var date_input = $('input[name="data_nascita"]'); //our date input has the name "data_nascita"
      var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "top"
      })
      date_input.on('changeDate', function(e) {
        date_input.blur()
      })
    })
```

```css
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
  <link id="bsdp-css" href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--  jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="invia_dati" onsubmit="return(validate());">
      <fieldset>


        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Invia Dati:</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="data_nascita">Data di Nascita</label>
          <div class="col-md-4 date">
            <input class="form-control" id="date" name="data_nascita" placeholder="13/11/1995" type="text" onblur="return(validate_field('date', 'dob-errore'));">
            <p id="dob-errore"> Questo campo non può essere vuotο</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="pob">Luogo di nascita</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="pob" name="pob" type="text" placeholder="i.e. Roma" class="form-control input-md" onblur="return(validate_field('pob', 'pob-errore'));">
            <p id="pob-errore"> Questo campo non può essere vuotο</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button (Double) -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="binvio"></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <button id="binvio" name="binvio" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Invio</button>
            <button id="bannulla" name="bannulla" type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse">Annulla</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this event from,

```
onblur="return(validate_field('date', 'dob-errore'));"
```

To, `onchange="return(validate_field('date', 'dob-errore'));"`

Maybe your issue is only with date picker right?